# Split date/time ranges into multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to split the date/time ranges in my dataset into multiple rows by hour in SQL Server. My current dataset looks like:

```
EmployeeCode         StartDateTime           EndDateTime
843578             2017-05-14 8:30 AM     2017-05-14 3:36 PM
587123             2017-05-14 9:00 AM     2017-05-14 6:28 PM
                  .....
```

And my current code seems like it's not catching both Date and Time element in the dataset. I want something like this as my final result.

```
EmployeeCode         StartDateTime           EndDateTime
843578             2017-05-14 8:30 AM     2017-05-14 9:00 PM
843578             2017-05-14 9:00 AM     2017-05-14 10:00 AM 
843578             2017-05-14 10:00 AM    2017-05-14 11:00 AM 
843578             2017-05-14 11:00 AM    2017-05-14 12:00 PM 
843578             2017-05-14 12:00 PM    2017-05-14 01:00 PM
843578             2017-05-14 01:00 PM    2017-05-14 02:00 PM
843578             2017-05-14 02:00 PM    2017-05-14 03:00 PM
843578             2017-05-14 03:00 PM    2017-05-14 03:36 PM
587123             2017-05-14 9:00 AM     2017-05-14 10:00 AM

                   ...............
```

I want to capture both date and time information and expand it to the rows by hour. Also, if an entry starts at 8:30 I want to split it as a separate unit such as 8:30 to 9:00 and the same logic is applied to the end time. (e.g. 3:00 - 3:36) My current code is not complete and I'd appreciate how I should rewrite the code to achieve what I mentioned above.

```
Select EmployeeCode, StartDateTime, EndDateTime
      ,StartTime = case when N=datepart(hour,StartDateTime) then StartTime else TimeFromParts(N,0,0,0,0) 
       end
      ,EndTime   = case when N=datepart(hour,EndDateTime)   then EndTime   else 
       TimeFromParts(N+1,0,0,0,0) end
      
 From  mytable T
 Join ( values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)
              ,(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13)
              ,(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20)
              ,(21),(22),(23)
       ) B(N)
  on  N between datepart(hour,StartDateTime) and datepart(hour,EndDateTime)
```

Comment: Will the start and end dates always be on the same date?

Comment: @Lamu Yes, the start and the end dates are the same and I just want to split the time by hour.

Comment: There is no `m` in my alias.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit messy, but using a few table constructors, you can create a tally and time ranges. Then you use a `CASE` expression to return the relevant values:

```sql
SELECT YT.EmployeeCode,
       CASE WHEN YT.StartDateTime > DT.StartDateTime THEN YT.StartDateTime ELSE DT.StartDateTime END AS StartDateTime,
       CASE WHEN YT.EndDateTime < DT.EndDateTime THEN YT.EndDateTime ELSE DT.EndDateTime END AS StartDateTime
FROM (VALUES(843578,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2017-05-14T08:30:00'),CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2017-05-14T15:36:00')),
            (587123,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2017-05-14T09:00:00'),CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2017-05-14T18:28:00')))YT(EmployeeCode,StartDateTime,EndDateTime)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23))T(I)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(DATEADD(HOUR,T.I,CONVERT(time(0),'00:00:00')),DATEADD(HOUR,T.I+1,CONVERT(time(0),'00:00:00'))))V(StartTime,EndTime)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(YT.StartDateTime),MONTH(YT.StartDateTime),DAY(YT.StartDateTime),DATEPART(HOUR,V.StartTime),DATEPART(MINUTE,V.StartTime),0,0),
                         DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(YT.StartDateTime),MONTH(YT.StartDateTime),DAY(YT.StartDateTime),DATEPART(HOUR,V.EndTime),DATEPART(MINUTE,V.EndTime),0,0)))DT(StartDateTime,EndDateTime)
WHERE YT.StartDateTime <= DT.EndDateTime
  AND YT.EndDateTime >= DT.StartDateTime;
```

---

From the comments, it looks(?) like the OP is using a Procedure to get the data, not a table as alluded to in the question, as they say that they can't use a `FROM`. You'll need to create a table, and then `INSERT` that data into it and reference it in the `FROM`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #t (EmployeeCode int,
                 StartDatetime datetime2(0),
                 EndDateTime datetime2(0));
INSERT INTO #t
EXEC dbo.YourProc {Parameters?};

--Then prior solution:
SELECT YT.EmployeeCode,
       ...
FROM #T YT
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(0),(1)....
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but the data I posted above was just a sample data, which only showed the top two observations in the entire dataset. The actual dataset I have is pretty big; more than 90000 obs. So if my understanding is correct, I don't think I can use the part in the FROM clause with my real data. Is there any way I could modify it to work with the bigger dataset?

Comment: Why doesn't the above work for your table, @alexsmith5123 ? Are `StartDateTime` and `EndDateTime` not an actual date and time data type and you're getting a conversion error? if so, then you need to fix that. The above would, with a table, scale fine.

Comment: *"I don't think I can use the part in the FROM clause with my real data"* What do you mean by this? Why can't your query use a `FROM`? If you can't use a `FROM` *how* are you getting the data *from* your table? Are you actually getting the data from a stored procedure? If so, insert the data from the procedure into a temporary table, and then refenece that `INSERT INTO #T EXEC YourSP; SELECT ...FROM #T CROSS APPLY (VAL...` etc

Comment: My understanding was you just listed the Employee ID in the VALUES parenthesis. For example, 843578 and 587123. And I was wondering if there is any way to do this without listing every single employee ID in the dataset because as I said, I have 90000+ observations in my actual dataset. I'm new to SQL so plz correct me if i'm wrong. Does it just mean I need to provide first two employee ID values like that?

Comment: I've updated the question to demonstrate how you would get the data from your procedure into a table, @alexsmith5123 .

Comment: *" And I was wondering if there is any way to do this without listing every single employee ID in the dataset "* You have a table; *you* don't need to list them. What's wrong with `FROM dbo.YourTable`?? Why can't you use a `FROM`?

Comment: I tried again and it works now. Thank you so much for your help. Appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome, @alexsmith5123 . Glad you got it working that time. If it does answer the question, please do consider marking it as the solution so that future readers now the answer was helpful.

Comment: You should consider doing the same with your [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14193972/alexsmith5123?tab=questions) that have received answers to too, @alexsmith5123 .

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you need?

```
Select
    EmployeeCode
,   final.startDateTime
,   final.endDateTime
from
    myTable as employee
    cross apply ( Select
        startDate = convert(date, startDateTime)
    ,   startHour = datepart(hour, startDateTime)
    ,   endDate = convert(date, endDateTime)
    ,   endHour = datepart(hour, endDateTime)
    ) as times
    cross apply (Select
        roundedStart = dateadd(hour, startHour, convert(datetime, startDate))
    ,   roundedEnd = dateAdd(hour, endHour + 1, convert(datetime, endDate))
    ) as rounding
    cross apply (Select
        [hours] = datediff(hour,roundedStart, roundedEnd)
    ) as diff
    cross apply (Select
        increment = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select NULL))
        from string_split(replicate(' ',diff.[hours] - 1),' ')
    ) as repeater
    cross apply ( Select
        startIncrement = dateadd(hour, repeater.increment - 1, roundedStart)
    ,   endInrement = dateadd(hour, repeater.increment, roundedStart)
    ) as timeIncrements
    cross apply (Select
        startDateTime = max(startDT)
    ,   endDateTime = min(endDT)
        from (values (employee.startDateTime, employee.endDateTime), 
                    (startIncrement, endInrement) ) s (startDT, endDT)
    ) as final
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good place to use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select employeecode, startdatetime as starthour,
             dateadd(hour, datepart(hour, startdatetime) + 1, convert(datetime, convert(date, startdatetime))) as endhour,
             enddatetime
      from t
      union all
      select employeecode, endhour,
             (case when dateadd(hour, 1, endhour) > enddatetime then enddatetime else dateadd(hour, 1, endhour) end),
             enddatetime
      from cte
      where endhour < enddatetime
     )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=811b456391b39c87343f33e1c89fd6c1) is a db<>fiddle.

If you can have more than 100 hours in a period (which seems unlikely because the periods appear to be on the same day), then you need `option (maxrecursion 0)`.